# Threema Lockscreen

Tags: android, security, lockscreen

lately I found out that the Threema application for andoid offers the possibility to use a system lockscreen inside the app

```
Threema > Settings > Security > Use system screen lock
```

Does anyone knows where I can find the documentation for this API?
I tried googling it, but it seems I dont find the right words or nobody has asked a question like this yet (which I doubt).

**Add:**
I think the SmartLock app by Google uses the same API (when you click on the Smart Lock entry in settings).

Thanks in advice,
floschlo

Comment: You could decompile the app to see how it does it.

Comment: As Threema is known for its strong security I bet they obfuscate their code very heavily

Comment: Same question, did you find a solution Florian?

Comment: Poorly I did not find a solution.